# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable: Where to fix?

Tags: web, cs50, nonetype

I am writing a web application called Finance for the assignment of the course CS50. The application runs well on my local server. However, when I checked my solution using a tool from the course, this is the error message I received:

```
:( logging in as registered user succceeds
sending POST request to /login
exception raised in application: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The log file showed no more information about the error.
Here is my related code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, InternalServerError
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Ensure responses aren't cached
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")

# Make sure API key is set
if not os.environ.get("API_KEY"):
    raise RuntimeError("API_KEY not set")

@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    # do something

@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    # do something

@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    # do something

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

# Forget any user_id
session.clear()

# User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
if request.method == "POST":

    # Ensure username was submitted
    if not request.form.get("username"):
        return apology("must provide username", 403)

    # Ensure password was submitted
    elif not request.form.get("password"):
        return apology("must provide password", 403)

    # Query database for username
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))

    # Ensure username exists and password is correct
    if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
        return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

    # Remember which user has logged in
    session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

    # Redirect user to home page
    return redirect("/")

# User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
else:
    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    # do something


@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    # do something

@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        # check if username and password are typed in
        if not username:
            return apology("no username")
        elif not password:
            return apology("no password")

        if password != confirmation:
            return apology("Password confirmation mismatched")
        else:
            users = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)
            if len(users) != 0:
                return apology("Invalid Username")
            else:
                pwd = generate_password_hash(password, method='pbkdf2:sha256', salt_length=8)
                db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(?, ?)", username, pwd)
                return redirect("/")
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")


@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
    # do something

def errorhandler(e):
    """Handle error"""
    if not isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        e = InternalServerError()
    return apology(e.name, e.code)

# Listen for errors
for code in default_exceptions:
    app.errorhandler(code)(errorhandler)
```

I would very much appreciate if you can tell me where I might have made the mistake or how I can figure out where to find the mistake.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: this is the source code of all my files in case anyone needs it https://github.com/sonpnt/sonpnt/tree/main/pset9/finance

Comment: You need to step through your code line by line and check where you are attempting to use a value that is None rather than the instance that you expect